# Powershell : Create runspace failed

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a C# component which executes Powershell scripts in powershell environment. Suddenly it started to show some issues, Now, when I try to execute the following, it shows exception

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.21.10.71 -Credential abc\admin
```

The exception is given below...

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : 
The WS-Management service cannot process the request. **This user is allowed a maximum 
number of 5 concurrent shells, which has been exceeded.** Close existing shells or raise 
the quota for this user. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting 
Help topic.
At line:1 char:16
+ Enter-PSSession <<<<  -ComputerName 192.21.10.71 -Credential abc\admin
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (192.21.10.71:String) [Enter-PSSession], 
PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

I fear, this is because I haven't properly closed / disposed the runspaces created in c# component.
Here is the code extracted from my component

```
    ......
Collection<PSObject> objPS = new Collection<PSObject>();
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(strUserName, password);
objRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
objRunspace.Open();
objPS = powershell.Invoke();
......
finally 
        {
            objRunspace.Dispose();
        }
```

I am beating the bush, instead of finding the root cause of this issue.

Thanks...

Comment: Are you explicitly closing the remote session (`Exit-PSSessuib`)? `Dispose` could just be disconnecting rather than shutting down.

Comment: What is the best method? How we can do Exit-PSSession in C# ?

Comment: In the PSH code (the C# creates a local Runspace so I assume you're connecting within the PSH code), otherwise if the runspace itself is remote (ie. not matching the C# code): [`Runspace.Disconnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.disconnect%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean, objRunspace.Close(); instead of objRunspace.Dispose();

Comment: A sample code would be helpful

Comment: That's not possible with the information provided: at no point in your C# code do you connect to a remote system, but the error – and the PSH code – show you are. Have you tried ensuring you are explicitly disconnecting your remote session?

Comment: The error message which is displayed above is from powershell console. But As I mentioned above, I fear, my c# code leaves the runspaces open and I doubt that causes the above error , when we try to execute script from powershell console.

Comment: Note the error message: the user is limited to 5 sessions. It doesn't matter if that session is from an interactive PSH prompt or PSH code wrapped in a .NET application: if they are the same user then they'll count to the session limit.